# Any idea why this function is causing segmentation fault core dumped? New CS50 week 4. C

Tags: c, cs50

I understand this may not be the most efficient code as I am new to this. I really have no idea why this is causing a segmentation fault and would greatly appreciate if somebody could explain to me where I have gone wrong. the function is supposed to blur a .bmp image by changing the colour value of each pixel to an average of itself and the 8 surrounding pixels. I have not yet wrote in where I will pass the blurred values to the output image. Thanks.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    float temp_red = 0, temp_green = 0, temp_blue = 0;
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            if (i >= 1 && j >= 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            if (i >= 1 && j + 1 <= width - 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            if (i >= 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            if (j >= 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            if (j + 1 <= width - 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            if (i + 1 <= height - 1 && j >= 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            if (i + 1 <= height - 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            if (i + 1 <= height - 1 && j + 1 <= width - 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            temp_red = temp_red + image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            temp_green = temp_green + image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;

            temp_red = round(temp_red / counter);
            temp_green = round(temp_green / counter);
            temp_blue = round(temp_blue / counter);
            counter = 0;
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = temp_red;
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp_green;
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp_blue;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Likely some index out of bounds of the array.

Comment: You have a condition `if (i-1 <=0 && j+1 <= width - 1)`.  What happens when `i = 0`?

Comment: The if function should run as it is less than or equal to should it not? It also should have been greater than, I have amended that now

Comment: @Iguananaut I have now changed the if 'i-1 >= 0' to 'if i >= 0' just realised how daft it was thanks. Still getting the error though if you have any more ideas :)

Comment: Hard to be sure then without more context

Comment: run it with a debugger like gdb, it will at least tell you where it's crashing, and unless things are totally hosed you'll be able to examine memory and variable values .. like what the indices are.

Comment: also what's that `return` at the bottom for? That means your outer loop only runs once.

Comment: @yano Good catch, it was supposed to be outside the loop it got messed up as ive been playing and changing things. Thanks

Comment: ah ok .. <O/T> but note that for `void` functions, there's no need to put `return` at the end, that's implied. Only reason to explicitly `return` is to return from the function earlier than the end.

Comment: can you run your code through GDB (or similar) and show us the output?

Comment: I have just run it on debug50 the CS50 debugger and found the it was in this if statement:
if (i+1 <= height - 1 && j >= 1)
            {
                temp_red = temp_red + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                temp_green = temp_green + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                temp_blue = temp_blue + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;


The i-1 should have been i+1

Comment: Sorry I thought the formatting would turn out better than that

Comment: @kenblitzer can you post how you are creating the `RGBTRIPLE image`, I feel like your error may lie there. I copied what I could and I did not run into a segmentation fault.

Comment: Note: `RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];` may too large for the stack.  Instead only 3 rows are needed.  Consider `RGBTRIPLE rowa[width], rowb[width], rowb[width];` and use a set of 3 pointers to rotate access to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (i-1 <=0 && j+1 <= width - 1)
```

i suspect that condition on i-1 is wrong, it gurahtees thatn you access index -1

i assume you mean

```
if (i-1 >=0 && j+1 <= width - 1)
```

---

other indexes are wrong too

```
        if (i + 1 <= height - 1 && j + 1 <= width - 1)
        {
            temp_red = temp_red + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed;
```

this will access image with index = height, you mean

```
        if (i + 1 < height - 1 && j + 1 < width - 1)
        {
            temp_red = temp_red + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed;
```

Comment: I believe you are right on that, I have corrected it. Thanks very much. I am still getting the segmentation fault, however.

Comment: @kenblitzer could you update your code to show the latest changes you have made on the question?

Comment: @HarryRamsey Updated now Harry